# Why does this left item provide more recovery than this right item?

Tags: diablo-iii

[image: Screenshot showing two item cards]

The right item has -9.2% recovery. Neither item has life on hit or life per second terms.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Recovery is a measure of how many **effective hit points** (EHP) you regenerate per second. It depends on both what was earlier called Healing (how much literal Life you recover) and damage mitigation.

The item on the right provides approximately the same Toughness, but *structure* of character's toughness changes - you have **more Life**, but **less Resistance**. So, despite your Healing recovering the same amount of Life as before, each of those hit points is less resistant to incoming damage, an hence worth less EHP.

Higher damage mitigation (Resistance, Armor, Dodge, Blocking, and other special effects) does effectively increase your Recovery by making your raw Life points worth more effective hit points.

Comment: It should depend on current stats, though. More resistance might not mean better recovery for an Int based character (Wizard, Witch Doctor), because their Int (hence their resistance) is typically very high and any addition to resistance will have diminishing returns, whereas Life added might serve more valuable. This is a theory and has not been tested.

Comment: @DrFish Sorry, I do not understand what you are trying to say. What exactly should depend on current stats? Item comparison percentages are already relative to your current stats, not some arbitrary default values.